# Framer Motion Reorder misplacing my items

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

For some reason, in the first "reordering" framer-motion miscalculates my items' position. It definitely has something to do with the fact that I'm using this within a side panel because it is positioning them to a distance in the x-axis precisely the same as the width of my panel. Another problem I'm having is that the AnimatePrescese applies the height animation to the element itself, but not to the children... Any suggestions?

```
        <Reorder.Group
            axis="y"
            className="flex flex-col p-0 m-0 list-none relative"
            values={orderedItems}
            onReorder={setOrderedItems}
            ref={listRef}
          >
            <AnimatePresence>
              {orderedItems?.map(item => {
                const {
                  id,
                  referencePayload: { abbreviation, description, title, url }
                } = item

                return (
                  <Reorder.Item
                    key={id}
                    value={item}
                    dragConstraints={listRef}
                    dragElastic={0.1}
                    dragMomentum={false}
                    onDragStart={() => onDragStart(id)}
                    onDragEnd={() => onDragEnd(id)}
                    initial={{ height: 0 }}
                    animate={{ height: 'auto' }}
                    exit={{ height: 0 }}
                  >
                    <ProductItem
                      id={id}
                      url={url}
                      abbreviation={abbreviation}
                      title={title}
                      description={description}
                      onRemoveItem={handleRemoveFavourite}
                      hasUpdateError={isRemovalError}
                      isDragging={activeItemId === id}
                    />
                  </Reorder.Item>
                )
              })}
            </AnimatePresence>
          </Reorder.Group>
```

Video with example => https://www.loom.com/share/cb2bf5f334f446459eeb1fc16772a3e4

Answer (score 0):

can you try to wrap the <.AnimatePresence> <ReOrder.Item> </ReOrder.Item></.AnimatePresence>
and then maybe forwardref of the animatePresence